# MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer has failed to stop

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

This error occurs when restarting or shutting down Tomcat. This is about the console.

```
Warning: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
     java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
     java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: Your title should include a summary of the error message, to distinguish from other Tomcat error Questions.

Comment: What version of Connector/J are you using? How are you using it? Where is the library .jar file located? Are you performing any clean-up when your application stops?